# how to trace running a file?

Tags: tail

I want to run a script (something.tcl) with a program (NS2-Network simulator )in Ubuntu 12.04. In order to run that program I have to write the below command:

```
NS something.tcl
```

when I type that command I see something like this for example

```
blah                  
bleh
bloo
```

My question is this: Is there any command in Ubuntu which tells me, for each line of that output which NS2 files write those?**Note:**I am sure those are not output of somthing.tcl

Comment: Why you need to know?

Comment: @Braiam :  In where I can find the file who show the first line or which file of the program produce the second line and etc ...My qusetion is this : is there any ubuntu command who tells me who is the source of those output or which file from my program produce this outputs?

Comment: Did you know about `watch` and `tail -f` commands?

Comment: @AvinashRaj would you please make examples for watch and tail -f . I saw watch is near to what I need